# How can one ensure only one instance of a View Model Base class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

I've been building a WPF application. Up till now, most ViewModels worked strictly off their own code.
I recently decided to create a base class "`ApplicationViewModel`" migrate common code into it. For the Most part this works fine, but I've run into an issue I'm having difficulty with.

It appears that my inheriting viewmodels are spawning their own instance of this base viewmodel. As a result; should a method in ClassA change a variable in the base class, then ClassB still registers the very same variable as null, or whatever it's previous value was.

Initially I thought registering the instance in Microsoft's Unity container would solve the issue,

```
public App()
{

    Container.RegisterType<ApplicationViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

but that changed nothing.

The obvious answer I found after research was to turn the class static, but I would prefer another solution before I head that route. Too much of my programs functionality may require reworking.

I'm not sure if a singleton Instance Property can even work with base class declarations.

So I suppose my question is: How would I ensure the same instance of this viewmodel base class is used throughout all my ViewModels?

Comment: if all viewmodels inherit from this base viewmodel then, single instance sharing is not possible and it does not even makes sense

Comment: Here's another angle; what is your use case for a single base class instance?

Comment: Post an outline of the class structure. A little C# is much clearer than a description. What you're describing isn't so obvious.

Comment: You're conflating base classes with static variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I ensure the same instance of this viewmodel base class is used throughout all my ViewModels?

Not possible. A base class is part of the definition of the class that inherits from it, i.e. the base class and the derived class are part of the very same instance. When you create an instance of the dervived class, only a single instance of that type is created. And the base type is part of this type.

If you only want a single instance of the base class around inheritance is not the solution.

Instead you could get a reference to the shared view model object using the `Container` from each of the child view models:

```
public class ChildViewModel //doesn't inhert from the base view model
{
    public ChildViewModel()
    {
        var sharedViewModel = Container.Resolve<ApplicationViewModel>();
        //call any properties or methods of the sharedViewModel...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this was educational. Much gratitude. Your solution was genius.

Answer (score 0):

If your viewmodels really (technically) inherit from the base class, this requires an instance of the base class per instance of the inherited viewmodel.

You could solve your problem by creating a static class (or singleton instance), which stores those values, which should be equal for all existing viewmodels.

Your base class can still contain non-static accessors (get-/set methods), which use these static variables. Your viewmodels do not need to know, where the values are stored, actually.

Actually, this would be really close to just defining some fields/properties static in your non-static base-class. So maybe this would also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no way to have different instance of derived class with one instance of the base class.

I can suggest just next design. In the base class create a field:

`private static Dictionary<string, object> _hash = new Dictionary<string, object>`

And create protected properties in the base class for derived classes:

```
 protected string Title {
 get { 
    string value;
    ApplicationViewModel._hash.TryGetValue("Title", out value);
    return value;
  }
  set {
    ApplicationViewModel._hash["Title"] = value;
  }
}
```

I hope that will suite for you.